# Limit on Runnable creation in java

Tags: java

I have a system which continuously receives messages. I need to pass these messages to a new system. But there will be millions of messages I will be sending here. I want to run this on a separate thread. In that case can we create millions of runnables to post the task on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: There is no limit on the creation of any object. Why should there be a limit on runnables?

Comment: You will not be satisfied with the performance (only when you have millions of processors on your machine).

Comment: @UweAllner The tasks will just queue. The OP says they are using a thread pull executor, which means there are N threads handling M tasks where usually N is less than the number of processors.

Comment: Better to use open source messaging queue libraries like `RabbitMQ`, `Apache ActiveMQ`, `Apache Kafka` and etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need to create millions of Runnable instances. I don't know other details of your system but it looks that you can send received message to a new system straight away after receiving.

If you wish to add some resistancy then you should consider using a message queue or a database to store received messages. That way you will guard them against being lost in case of a crash/process exit. And a separate thread pool should be processing messages from this storage (queue or database) by sending to a new system.